# Chrome on Android 14 does not show the option to open the camera when uploading an image

Tags: google-chrome, android-camera, android-14, android-photo-picker

We have an Angular 13 app and we are using `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` to upload an image. Up to Android 13, Chrome showed two options:

1. Open the camera to take a picture
2. Select an existing image from the gallery

But on Android 14 Chrome only shows the option to select an existing image, it doesn't show the option to open the camera.

We have seen the issue in differnt device models, such as Google Pixel or Samsung Galaxy, running Android 14.

Both options are shown in Chrome on older Android versions.

Anyone facing the same issue? Has anybody found how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We have basically the same problem. It occurs without any framework - just plain html:

A) `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` will give access to image files only without the option to capture from camera.

B) `<input type="file" accept="image/*,text/plain">` DOES give the option to capture from camera, at the same time allows to select ANY file type.

---

We have observed this only on Android 14 with Chrome + Edge, not with Firefox + Samsung Browser.

This behaviour seems very strange and does not seem to be intended. A bug report was filed to Google back in November 23 but not processed in any way so far.

Due to the userAgent reduction it is unfortunately not even possible to implement B as a workaround for affected devices only.

Comment: If the link to the bug-report is public, could you provide this as well in the answer?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was useful. It definetly looks like a Chrome + Android 14 bug. Adding `text/plain` could be a temporary workaround but it is not ideal. We tested it and it does show the two options (camera and file picker).

As @DarkBee pointed, would you be able to provide the link to the Google bug-report? It would be useful for tracking. Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The bug tracker link is unfortunately not public. Sorry.