# File upload: trigger mobile devices to offer camera

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

I noticed on a site (that I cannot share unfortunately), that the file upload triggers an interesting behavior.

Assume this simple markup:

```html
<input value="" name="form-field-1" id="form-field-1" type="file" required="true">
<label for="form-field-1">choose picture</label>
```

When clicked in Chrome on an Android device, the browser doesn’t bring up the usual file picker, but a reduced interface, that emphasizes the camera:

[image: screenshot of the interface]

This is also notably different from when the [`capture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture) attribute is used (in which case the camera starts immediately).

And the input hasn’t got any `accept="image/*"` or similar hints to the browser. I found no click event handlers or other JS trickery as well.

What is it that triggers this behavior of mobile Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873768/android-14-photo-picker-camera-tile-removed-from-google-chrome) one solution is an input with `accept="image/*,text/plain"` and no `capture`. I could successfully trigger the picker with that code.

I assume my mysterious form adds this attribute on demand for mobile devices.